# Why \empty and \isset are not allowed in php

Tags: php

AFAIK [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) are **normal** [php](/questions/tagged/php) functions. When I try the following I get a **parse error**

```
if (\empty($array)) {
   // .....
}
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'empty' (T_EMPTY), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in

This seems strange to me because other [php](/questions/tagged/php) functions http://php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php such as `\is_array`, `\is_null`, `\is_object`, `\strpos` etc... allow backslash.

Why are these (at least) two functions different?

Comment: The error sounds like you're missing a `;` or something as `empty` and `isset` are supported in PHP. What's the actual line of code causing this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> AFAIK [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) are **normal** [php](/questions/tagged/php) functions.

They are not. They are *language constructs*, which you can read as *keywords*. If they would play by the normal rules of functions, they couldn't do what they are doing. `isset($foo)` would always trigger an error about undefined variables, since PHP would try to resolve the variable `$foo` before passing *its value* to the function `isset`. That is clearly against what those *language constructs* are supposed to do.

Comment: So `isset` is not a function and cannot be a function in order to handle not defined variable without sending out errors/warnigs. That's very clear, thanks. But what about `empty`? why isn't it a normal function as it behaves exactly like one

Comment: No, `empty` doesn't behave like a function in the same way that `isset` doesn't behave like one: it explicitly handles undefined variables.

Comment: You might be interested in: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)